# what do I need to unzip after downloading ubuntu-13.10-amd64.iso

Tags: installation

Dumb question but I dont know what I need to do next after downloading ubuntu-13.10?
I've read I need to burn it to a cd but the all the files in the folder are zipped. Do I need to extract them all on my PC (Windows 7) and then burn them all or just the OS (I gues the big files) Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

It is an iso or image file. If you do not have CD / DVD burning software installed, windows defaults to (mis) identifying the file as a .zip file.

You do not extract anything, you either burn a DVD or make a live flash drive. Live flash is more modern (I have not burned a DVD in more then 4 years).

See:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 1):

If you want to burn it to a CD or DVD you need a program that can burn ISO files

I suggest Imgburn for windows which can be found here:
http://www.filehippo.com/download_imgburn/
just click the "download latest version" link next to the green arrow on the right side of the screen

Once you download imgburn install the program

After you install it run the program and you will come to a screen with many different options

(bear with me as im typing this from memory and not using the program because i cant on linux)

Choose burn iso to disk and then insert your cd or dvd
where it shows the path for the iso click the folder icon on the right of the path bar
select the iso that you downloaded
once you do that select the burn option on the bottom of the screen and it will start buring

Rule of thumb with burning ISO's:
The slower the burn speed the less room the program has to make errors. although I usally just leave to at max and never had a problem is your not sure then set the speed to 1x or 2x.

Making a Ubuntu USB:
follow the instructions here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

hope this helps
if you still dont get it email me at lf61891@gmail.com and i can put together a quick video on how to do it. I have windows 8.1 but its the same thing for 7&8